# "[TTM] Buffer eviction failed" on Ubuntu turn off

Tags: shutdown, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, restart

I am getting this error message when trying to reset or turn off my PC with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
[150.622847] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
```

Then the PC won't turn off and I have to force it by holding the power button.

This has been going on for 2 weeks now. For what I've looked for, this may be related to the video card (but I couldn't find in what way). My specs:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit
Processor: Intel Core i5-5200U 2.20GHz x 4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) Memory: 7,7 GiB
Graphics (off-board not listed): AMD Radeon R7 M270
```

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting this problem anymore.

Looks like I fixed it updating my Ubuntu kernel. I did this update a couple months ago and this never happened again.

Check out this answer for how to update the kernel:

[How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

Hope it fix this for who is going by the same problem!